# Connected graph with no triangle

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a simple graph on $k$ vertices without any cycle of length $3$ and every vertex in $G$  has degree at least $\frac{k+1}{4}$. Show $G$ is connected.

I assume that $G$ is not connected. Then there exists 2 vertices $u, v$ of $G$ such that there is no path from $u$ to $v$. Then I tried to find the number of vertices of $G$ which includes $u, v$ and their $\frac{k+1}{4}$ neighbors to get a contradiction. I don't know how to use the triangle-free assumption.

Any hint is highly appreciated.

Comment: One thing I would try is: Suppose $G$ is not connected. Then $G$ has at least $2$ components, all of which are triangle-free (without any cycle of length $3$). Let $H$ be a component of $G$. Perhaps try and contradict [Mantel's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n%27s_theorem#Mantel's_theorem) by arguing that $H$ has too many edges (sum of degrees, halved) given $\delta (H) \ge \frac{k+1}{4}$ and $|V(H)| < k$ by more than some amount.

Comment: I noticed Hendrix's suggestion as I was writing up exactly the same idea.  I hadn't realized that Turan's theorem had a special name for the length-3 case, so I incorporated the name "Mantel's Theorem."

Answer (score 1):

Assume $G$ is not connected, and let $H$ be a component of $G$ with the fewest vertices $m$.  Then $H$ contains at most half the vertices of $G$:  i.e.,
$$
m \le \frac{k}{2}.
$$
Because each vertex has degree at least $(k+1)/4$, the number of edges of $H$ satisfies
$$
\frac{m}{2}\frac{k+1}{4} \le E(H).
$$
However, Mantel's Theorem for triangle-free graphs states that
$$
E(H) \le \frac{m^2}{4}.
$$
Combining the two inequalities for $E(H)$ and dividing by $m/4$ yields
$$
\frac{k+1}{2} \le m,
$$
which contradicts the first inequality.